# How do I regenerate thumbnails?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I just got a new theme and am trying to regenerate thumbnails. I'm having trouble though. I tried using the AJAX Thumbnail Rebuilder but for 5 hours it just said reading attachments. Then I tried the normal rebuilder but the vast majority of images came back as undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled post-thumbnails in your functions.php file?

Comment: yes I have, I have thumbnails showing up on the site, just not correctly (http://dev.wegotthiscovered.com)

Comment: even for the ones that it said it re-sized, it did't, not one image worked

Answer (score 9):

i have only had to do this on a couple of occasions, but each time i have used this [**regenerate thumbnails plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) on each occasion with a 100% success rate, however (as you will expect it did take quite a bit of time as i had over a 1000 images that it had to wade its way through on each occasion.

Comment: I did this and out of 6000 images, about 3500 came back as undefined, any idea why?

Comment: did you try this: http://www.jdhodges.com/2011/05/plugin-regenerate-thumbnails-error-undefined-solved/

Comment: No but all my images are in the same folder, so if it can access some with the 755 permissions, shouldn't it be able to access all?

Answer (score 4):

I find the [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) to be better than the regenerate thumbnails plugin, because it doesn't tie up your server as bad, allows you to skip certain sizes (which saves time), and gives more visual feedback.

Comment: I tried it with only doing one size and still, for hours and hours it just showed me that message "reading attachments"

Answer (score 0):

@Matt

From *my personnal experience*, *and about half a million other people*, [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) is the best thumbnails regenerator I have ever used.
Hope this will help you.